# Android not compiling because manifest 'error: cannot find symbol class Manifest'

Tags: android, android-studio, window

When i compile my project in Android Studio i have this error

> error: cannot find symbol class Manifest

but when i remove this line 'import tld.domain.appname.Manifest;', everything seems to work fine.
In other Android Studios, the compilation of the project works correctly with the same import.

The import is required for this block of code

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mView.getTarget(), Manifest.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS);
   if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mView.getTarget(),
               new String[]{Manifest.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS},
               Constants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_MANAGE_ACCOUNTS);
   }
```

The permission i want to reference is bellow.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

The projects are exactly the same, i have no clue what's the problem.
Thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: try to clean and build

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle I already tried but didn't work

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches / restart...

Comment: can you include the error schreenshot?

Comment: Where and why do you want to import the Manifest? Or is it a `Manifest` class that has nothing related to the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: @Eselfar thank you for your time. The Manisfest is related with the Android Manifest. I updated my question so you can see why i need this import.

Comment: As @Mihai mentioned below, you are importing the wrong class. That's why it doesn't work

Comment: Hi @Elsefar, my way to import the manifest is not wrong. The exact same code work in other windows and linux machine. It has to be something else

Comment: Hi @HasibAkter i just uploaded a screenshot. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score -5, accepted):

so i updated the version of play services plus and play services auth on my build.gradle(module:app) and the problem just disappeared

Answer (score 6):

Try to import manifest by

> import android.Manifest

And use android.manifest in your code instead of just Manifest.

Comment: Hi  @Miha, my way to import the manifest is not wrong. The exact same code work in other windows and linux machine. It has to be something else

Comment: It works, but i need to compile with the other import because it refers to a different Manifest option

Comment: Then rephrase your question to make the expected result more clear.